# HasData не работает с зависимыми свойствами

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть моделька User, которая внутри себя имеет зависимое свойство Phone.

Это все таким образом конфигурируется в `UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>`
в методе:

```
Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
```

builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Phone);

Вроде бы все норм и база успешно создается => косяков в настройках у меня нету.

Но если я хочу задать какие-то стартовые значения в этой конфигурации для User через `builder.HasData`, то ловлю ошибку:

> The seed entity for entity type 'User' cannot be added because another
>   seed entity with the same key value for {'Id'} has already been added.
>   Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to
>   see the conflicting key values.

Как я понимаю- это из-за зависимого свойства.

Неужели так делать не правильно:

```
  builder.HasData(new User()
    {
        Id = 0,
        Phone = new PhoneNumber()
        {
            Number = "12354",
            IsConfirmed = true
        }
    });
```

?
Как тогда делать иначе?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поставить Id отличный от нуля (значения по умолчанию):

```
  builder.HasData(new User()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Phone = new PhoneNumber()
        {
            Number = "12354",
            IsConfirmed = true
        }
    });
```

Ответ подсмотрен [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50010614/8324991)

Но если обязательно нужен Id = 0, то можно посмотреть [другой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56657516/8324991) ответ по ссылке, там нашли как обойти ограничение, написав своё расширение.

Comment: А мне именно 0 нужен. Не спрашивайте почему... просто так надо...

Comment: @iluxa1810 Тогда почитайте следующий ответ за тем, что по ссылке, там вроде нашли как обойти это ограничение